# Why is this statement of logical equivalence true? f ∨ g ∧ h ≡ (f ∨ g) ∧ (f ∨ h)

Tags: equivalent, formal-languages, reasoning, truthtable

Why is this statement of logical equivalence true?

```
f ∨ g ∧ h ≡ (f ∨ g) ∧ (f ∨ h)
```

I made the truth tables below, and this statement doesn´t hold--it isn't a logical equivalence. However, according to the exercise it is.

`f ∨ g ∧ h`:

[image]

`(f ∨ g) ∧ (f ∨ h)`:

[image]

Comment: This would depend on *operator precedence*.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: I think this question fits better on other stack exchange websites, it's only loosely related to software development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a close look at the way the equivalence is denoted:
*no* parenthesis on the left side, two on the right specifying the disjunctions to be evaluated first.
*If* this was the conventional [logical operator precedence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_operator#Order_of_precedence), both pairs of parentheses were dispensable.
If *left to right* evaluation was conventional, the first pair was redundant: the convention actually is *conjunction before disjunction* (and the equivalence is denoted correctly as well as irredundant).

So, the *f ∨ g* column in your first table is immaterial, if correct.
The *f ∨ g ∧ h* column is inconsistent: the label with explicit parentheses would need to be *f ∨ (g ∧ h)*, the values tabulated are for *(f ∨ g) ∧ h*.